# vue-agile slider -- Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm pulling my hair out trying to crack this one. I've read a bunch of solutions but none seem to work, or my implementation is wrong.

My slider loads but when I click the Next button, it switches but then slide #1 always snaps back over, as if it's determined to perpetually be the "active" slide. What's weird is that sometimes when I make a change and Webpack re-bundles, the slider then works perfectly (and I notice that the class "agile__slide" has been added to each slide, and "active__slide" for the active one). If I refresh the page, it breaks and slides no longer have the "agile__slide" class. Help me Obi Wan...

Template:

```
<agile
  v-if="isSlideLoaded"
  ref="main"
  class="slider-wrap"
  :options="options1"
>
  <a
    :class="`slide--${index}`"
    :index="index"
    :key="`cat-${index}`"
    @click.stop="navigateToPlayground(category)"
    class="slide"
    v-for="(category, index) in categories"
  >
    <div
      class="slider-image"
      :class="{
              'no-bg-image': category.category_image.length === 0
            }"
      :style="{
              background: `url(${category.category_image.thumbnails.large.url})`
            }"
    >
      <span class="text">{{ category.category_name }}</span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <template slot="prevButton">
    <button
      @click="$refs.main.goToPrev()"
      type="button"
      class="agile__nav-button agile__nav-button--next"
    >
      <svg
        width="8"
        viewBox="0 0 11 20"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path d="M10 1L1 10L10 19" stroke="#1A120F" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </template>
  <template slot="nextButton">
    <button
      @click="$refs.main.goToNext()"
      type="button"
      class="agile__nav-button agile__nav-button--next"
    >
      <svg
        width="8"
        viewBox="0 0 11 20"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path d="M1 1L10 10L1 19" stroke="#1A120F" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </template>
</agile>
```

And...

```
  data() {
    return {
      asNavFor1: [],
      isSlideLoaded: false,
      options1: {
        dots: false,
        fade: false,
        navButtons: true,
        infinite: true
      },
      slides: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.isSlideLoaded = true;
    this.asNavFor1.push(this.$refs.main);
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.asNavFor1.push(this.$refs.main);
    });
  },
```

Comment: my hunch is that the `<a>` link is playing spoilsport. To debug, you might want to temporarily remove it and run the loop on the inner `div` (after adding the slide class) and checking work again.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

`v-if="categories"` was incorrect. It need to be `v-if="categories.length"`. I did not need any isSlideLoaded variable at all.

```
<agile
  v-if="categories.length"
  ref="main"
  class="slider-wrap"
  :options="options"
>
  ...
<script>
...
data() {
  return {
    options: {
      dots: false,
      fade: false,
      navButtons: true,
      infinite: true
    }
  };
}
... 
</script>
```

Comment: useful answer !